# How can I generate a youtube style unique alphanumeric id model id in django

Tags: django, rest, model

I want dont want to use the django id directly for viewsets in django, since that potentially reveals the number of items.
I already figured out how to generate UUIDs, which work, but are unwieldy and hexadecimal.
Is there a way to generate a guaranteed unique sufficently long alphanummeric string in django similar to a uuid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably do something like this (although untested):

```
import random, string

def random_id_field():
  rnd_id = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=16))
  return rnd_id

class MyModel(models.Model):
  id = models.Charfield(max_length=16, unique=True, primary_key=True, default=random_id_field)
```

**Update**

In Python 3.6, they introduced the concept of `secrets`. Here is an example:

```
from secrets import token_urlsafe
random_string = token_urlsafe(16)
print(random_string)
```

Result: `'x3jFt0X_hZr2B4j6CexixQ'`

Comment: Was hoping for a more standardaized version honestly. What happens when 2 identical fields are generated? Does it run again or just crash?

Comment: That's why it's 16 characters - to prevent that from happening.

Comment: ok thanks but isn't 16 way too low to prevent collisions then?

Comment: I’m not sure the min length. Honestly, I use UUID. It’s just simpler

Comment: yeah ill porbably just use that too